# Java MPG calculator

Tags: java

I've finished most of the code for a simple [MPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuel_economy_in_automobiles#Units_of_measure) calculator. My main issue right now is at the end of the program I need it to calculate the average MPG of all of the miles the user decides to enter in.

I'm getting some number, but it isn't the correct one. If you could beseech your knowledge on me, that would be amazing. Please let me know if there are other problems as well, I'm up to whatever criticism.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GasMileage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GasMileage mileage1 = new GasMileage();
        GasMileage mileage2 = new GasMileage();

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome to the MPG calculator!");
        double counterM;
        double counterG;
        double mileage;
        double gallons;
        double mpg;
        double average;

        String repeat = "yes";

        while (repeat.equals("Yes") ||
               repeat.equals("yes") ||
               repeat.equals("y") ||
               repeat.equals("Y")) {

            System.out.println("Enter miles driven: ");
            mileage = input.nextDouble();
            counterM = mileage++;
            mileage1.setMilesDriven(mileage);
            mileage2.setMilesDriven(counterM);

            System.out.println("Enter gallons used: ");
            gallons = input.nextDouble();
            counterG = gallons++;
            mileage1.setGallonsUsed(gallons);
            mileage2.setGallonsUsed(counterG);

            mileage1.setMpg(mileage, gallons);
            mileage2.setMpg(counterM, counterG);
            mpg = mileage1.getMpg();
            System.out.println("Your mpg is: " + mpg);

            System.out.println("repeat? ");
            repeat=input.next();
        }

        average = mileage2.getMpg();
        System.out.println("Your total average mpg is: " + average);
    }

    double milesDriven;
    double gallonsUsed;
    double mpg1;

    public void setMilesDriven(double Miles) {
        milesDriven = milesDriven + Miles;
    }
    public void setGallonsUsed(double Gallons) {
        gallonsUsed = gallonsUsed+Gallons;
    }

    public double getMilesDriven() {
        return milesDriven;
    }

    public double getGallonsUSed() {
        return gallonsUsed;
    }

    public void setMpg(double setM, double setG) {
        mpg1 = (setM) / setG;
    }

    public double getMpg() {
            return mpg1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're setting the values of the `mileage2` to a counter variable. This will return a constant result based on the counter's iteration, not based on the average of the entries.. Consider using a `List<Double>` to store the results of all `mileage1.getMpg()` calls, then use that list to find the average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mileage++` will actually increase the value of mileage.

```
int mileage = 1;
int gallons = mileage++; // mileage will equal 2 after this
```

As a side note never wait until the end to clean/format your code. Clean code will be easier to read hence easier to spot problems.

Comment: Ahh, thank you. I'm just starting to really understand loops and counters but that makes sense.
Also I'll definitely reformatting earlier, I just got into a grove when I started coding left it as is. :)

Comment: Too many developers get used to "cleaning code" after they get it working. Its a good habit to break early.

Answer (score 1):

I found few problem in the code:

- Use `repeat.equalsIgnoreCase("YES")` instead.
- Why mileage++ & gallons++, this will change your input.
- `setMpg()` is not using values which is already present in the Object.
- `mileage1` is not resetting inside the loop so previous results will be updated instead of creating new result.

If I am not wrong, you want to print the Mileage for each trip and overall mileage. So updated code will be like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GasMileage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GasMileage mileage2 = new GasMileage();

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome to the MPG calculator!");
        double mileage;
        double gallons;
        double mpg;
        double average;

        String repeat = "yes";

        while (repeat.equalsIgnoreCase("YES")) {
            GasMileage mileage1 = new GasMileage();
            System.out.println("Enter miles driven: ");
            mileage = input.nextDouble();
            mileage1.setMilesDriven(mileage);
            mileage2.setMilesDriven(mileage);

            System.out.println("Enter gallons used: ");
            gallons = input.nextDouble();
            mileage1.setGallonsUsed(gallons);
            mileage2.setGallonsUsed(gallons);

            mpg = mileage1.getMpg();
            System.out.println("Your mpg is: " + mpg);

            System.out.println("repeat? ");
            repeat = input.next();

        }

        average = mileage2.getMpg();
        System.out.println("Your total average mpg is: " + average);
    }

    double milesDriven;
    double gallonsUsed;
    double mpg1;

    public void setMilesDriven(double Miles) {
        milesDriven = milesDriven + Miles;
    }

    public void setGallonsUsed(double Gallons) {
        gallonsUsed = gallonsUsed + Gallons;
    }

    public double getMilesDriven() {
        return milesDriven;
    }

    public double getGallonsUSed() {
        return gallonsUsed;
    }

    public double getMpg() {
        return milesDriven / gallonsUsed;
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Welcome to the MPG calculator!
Enter miles driven:  100
Enter gallons used:  25
Your mpg is: 4.0

repeat? yes
Enter miles driven:  200
Enter gallons used:  20
Your mpg is: 10.0
repeat? n

Your total average mpg is: 6.666666666666667 (300 / 45)
```

If you want incremental mileage then move back mileage1 outside the loop. So output will be like:

```
Welcome to the MPG calculator!
Enter miles driven:  100
Enter gallons used:  25
Your mpg is: 4.0

repeat? yes
Enter miles driven:  200
Enter gallons used:  20
Your mpg is: 6.666666666666667
repeat? n

Your total average mpg is: 6.666666666666667 (300 / 45)
```